# How do I get the last x days using DateTimeIndex in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to get the last x days from my data. I use a DateTimeIndex as an index.

The following is a simplified way I use:

```
end_date = df.last_valid_index()
start_date = end_date - pd.tseries.offsets.DateOffset(30, "D")
df = df.loc[start_date:]
```

Sometimes, I get a `KeyError` followed by the timestamp of the start date.
I think this occurs when that `start_date` is not found on the `DateTimeIndex`.

Comment: What you suggest will take the date from the first valid index of the whole dataframe, not just the period I am interested in.

Comment: This question could really use an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20159305/7311767)